# In Drupal 7 how do I add an anchor tag to a path alias menu link

Tags: 7, routes, path-aliases, navigation

I created a node in drupal 7 and given it a url path alias of 'testing'.   When I try to create a menu item that links to the path alias with an anchor, it throws an error 
[image]

If I do `node/1#this` it works, but again not with a url path alias.

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the full url with the anchor tag. Not the best for deployment but a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I found adding the page path without it's alias would validate the form.

For example: "node/1#top"

Although, I now have an .active-trail and .active class issue on the menu item/link.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for the active class issue?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function phptemplate_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($original_path);
    $url = parse_url($alias);

    if (isset($url['fragment'])){
        //set path without the fragment
        $path = $url['path'];

        //prevent URL from re-aliasing
        $options['alias'] = TRUE;

        //set fragment
        $options['fragment'] = $url['fragment'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In search for an answer for my colleague I found a gist.

You guys can try it out.

https://gist.github.com/932595

I have not worked on this.

Comment: Have you used this code? Did you find it worked?

Comment: @InfluenceJamie No, I have not.